# API WordPress is Limited? Return False

Tags: plugin-development, api, xml-rpc

We are migrating a school library repository to the CMS WordPress and so make it public and accessible to society.

All items are scanned and available for up to WordPress via API wp.uploadFile wp.newPost.

We succeeded to 327 items and after that the return is only False.

Even debugging and sending simple messages, we have not succeeded.

By contrast, the images that go up by another separate script continues to rise and is 800,000 uploads.

Even when we disable the sending of images we have success and keeps returning False.

What can it be?

This is simple Code. Working in local Host and not on Server after 327 Post

```
$usr = 'user';
$pwd = 'pass';
$xmlrpc = 'http://domain.edu.br/xmlrpc.php';
$client = new IXR_Client($xmlrpc);

$client -> debug = true; //optional but useful

$params = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_title' => 'Test Title',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_thumbnail' => 3,
    'comment_status' => 'open',
    'post_excerpt' => 'description',
    'post_content' => 'Content'             

);


$res = $client -> query('wp.newPost',1, $usr, $pwd, $params);
```

Comment: if one script works and the other doesn't, then what is the difference between them?

Comment: Exactly inherit the same Class. The difference is that one does uploads and the other makes posts to the content and its Taxonomy.

Even the simple I just put to you see, it does not work.

Comment: did you check that you are not out of storage space?

Comment: Remaining 95% of the HD.

Comment: seems like you should post the script and how you use it. the code above is probably the wrong script

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting anything meaningful from API responses I would recommend to enable `WP_DEBUG` and logging server–side. Though in many cases WP doesn’t handles error silently, so you might need to add and log some checks of your own to source.

As a more general advice XMLRPC is sort of dusty. New [REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/) is being developed and (slowly) added to core, you could try with that one.